# Zurb Foundation 6 app.scss vs _settings.scss

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

What is the difference between `app.scss` vs `_settings.scss` in  **Zurb Foundation 6**?

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). It's not clear what you are asking for. Have you checked the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

`app.scss` basically takes all of the Foundation `.scss` files and whatever custom `.scss` you have made and compiles them together into one `css` file. The `_settings.scss` is for overriding default `.scss` variables without editing the core `scss` files.